# How to send structure array to function in C?

Tags: arrays, function, structure

Hi I'm having trouble sending an array of structures to a function.
The structure is set up as below:

```
struct Leader
{
   char surname[15], party[15];
   int months_in_power;
};
```

I then read the data from a file and assign it:

```
if ((INFILE=(fopen("PM.txt","r"))) == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("ERROR: The file could not be opened."); 
    system("pause"); 
    return 1; 
}

while(fscanf(INFILE, "%s %d %d %d %d %s", name, 
&start_month, &start_year, &end_month, &end_year, party)>0)
{
    struct Leader PM[i];
    strcpy(PM[i].surname, name);
    strcpy(PM[i].party, party);
    months = tenure(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year);
    PM[i].months_in_power = months;
    party_time(&PM[i], &Con_months, &Lab_months );
    printf("%s: %s, %d months\n", PM[i].surname, PM[i].party, PM[i].months_in_power); //This line all works
    i++;
}
```

Then I try and call my function 'bubble'.

```
imax=i;
bubble(PM, imax);
```

and the function bubble is supposed to sort them in order.

```
void bubble(struct Leader arr[],int max)
{
    int j=0, i=0, temp=0;

    for (j=1; j<(max);j++)
    {   
        for (i=0; i<(max-1); i++)
        {
        if (arr[i].months_in_power < arr[i+1].months_in_power)
        { 
            temp = arr[i].months_in_power;
            arr[i].months_in_power=arr[i+1].months_in_power;
            arr[i+1].months_in_power = temp;
        }
            else continue;
        }
    } 

    for( i=0; i<max; i++) 
    {printf("%d\n", arr[i].months_in_power);} 

    return ;        
}
```

If I try and print arr[i].months_in_power during the sorting loops it just prints rubbish and crashes. Whats wrong?

EDIT: The PM.txt file contains information like:

Attlee         7   1945  10  1951 Labour

Churchill     11   1951   5  1955 Conservative

Eden           6   1955  12  1956 Conservative

etc etc...

Thanks

Comment: post a few lines of your data file `PM.txt` that will help us understand where array overflow may be occurring, if at all.

Comment: I edited the original question to add a few lines

Comment: Good, post your `tenure()` (which looks like it calculates months during tenure?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you did not create an instance of the `PM` array or structs. Other than a few other nits, and your sort being in descending order (check the bubble sort logic), the code was not in bad shape. **Note:** when you are creating an array of some size, it is general practice to `#define` a maximum size of the array. Below, I just defined `MAXS` (max structures) to `256` in the line `#define MAXS 256`. You then check your count as you read from your data file against `MAXS-1` (zero based array count). If you exceed `MAXS - 1` you will need to increase the size (or if you allocated dynamically, you have the option to reallocate at that point) The example below ran fine.

Remember to **initialize all variables!** This is one of the easiest things you can do to prevent wandering off into undefined behavior.

**Note:** I created a `tenure` to return the number of months served -- make sure that is what you want. Also, I did not recreate a `party_time` function. That's up to you.

Let me know if you need any additional help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 256

struct Leader
{
    char surname[15];
    char party[15];
    int months_in_power;
};

void bubble (struct Leader arr[],int max);
int tenure (int start_month, int start_year, int end_month, int end_year);

int main () {

    char name[64] = {0};
    char party[64] = {0};
    int start_month=0, start_year=0, end_month=0, end_year=0;
    int months = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int imax = 0;
    FILE *INFILE;

    struct Leader PM[MAXS] = {{ {0}, {0}, 0 }};

    if ((INFILE = (fopen ("PM.txt","r"))) == NULL) 
    { 
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: The file could not be opened."); 
        return 1; 
    }

    while(fscanf(INFILE, "%s %d %d %d %d %s", name, 
    &start_month, &start_year, &end_month, &end_year, party)>0)
    {
        strcpy(PM[i].surname, name);
        strcpy(PM[i].party, party);
        months = tenure(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year);
        PM[i].months_in_power = months;
        // party_time(&PM[i], &Con_months, &Lab_months );
        printf("%-12s: %-12s, %d months\n", PM[i].surname, PM[i].party, PM[i].months_in_power); //This line all works

        i++;

        if (i > MAXS - 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Error: lines read from file exceed MAXS, reallocate or increase size.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    imax=i;
    bubble(PM, imax);

    return 0;
}

void bubble(struct Leader arr[],int max)
{
    int j=0, i=0, temp=0;

    for (j=1; j<(max);j++)
    {   
        for (i=0; i<(max-1); i++)
        {
        if (arr[i].months_in_power < arr[i+1].months_in_power)
        { 
            temp = arr[i].months_in_power;
            arr[i].months_in_power=arr[i+1].months_in_power;
            arr[i+1].months_in_power = temp;
        }
            else continue;
        }
    } 

    for( i=0; i<max; i++) 
    {printf("%d\n", arr[i].months_in_power);} 

    return ;        
}

int tenure (int start_month, int start_year, int end_month, int end_year) 
{
    int no_months = (end_year - start_year) * 12 - start_month + end_month;
    return (start_year <= end_year) ? no_months : -(no_months);
}
```

**input:**

```
$ cat PM.txt
Attlee 7 1945 10 1951 Labour
Churchill 11 1951 5 1955 Conservative
Eden 6 1955 12 1956 Conservative
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/structleader
Attlee      : Labour      , 75 months
Churchill   : Conservative, 42 months
Eden        : Conservative, 18 months
75
42
18
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that sorted everything

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the following code is correct

```
struct Leader PM[i];
strcpy(PM[i].surname, name);
strcpy(PM[i].party, party);
```

You first declare an array of Leader structures of size i, which can be correct, but then you try to access it with PM[i]. PM[i] will fetch data beyond the array and strcpy will write into memory which doesn't belong to the array.

Later on, when you try to access data it might be garbage.

Comment: I don't think that is an issue. `i` is controlled by the lines read from the text file `PM.txt` and cannot cause a read beyond end of data or array.